# Проблема с позиционированием блоков(второй уходит нижу первого)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Привет у меня есть сайт на котором я делал меню в котором можно отсортировать товар.Это меню должно состоять с двух блоков, но правый блок ушел ниже левого и я не пойму почему так происходит.Проект делаю на React.

Вот так выглядит сейчас мой сайт.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сдесб вы можете найти полный репозиторий проекта https://github.com/fpsstyle228/portland.com

СSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-regular';
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.svg#Montserrat Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold';
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.svg#Montserrat SemiBold') format('svg');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}

*{
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: #B9BED1 !important;
  color: #B9BED1 !important;
  height: 1px;
}
input,select {outline:none;}


input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 12px
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 12px
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 12px
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 12px
}

/* ______________________________________________________________________________ШАПКА САЙТА(Header.js) */

.MenuButtons {
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.MenuButtons>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.MenuButtons>li>a {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 29px;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.MenuButtons>li>div>span {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.MenuButtons>li>img {
  margin-right: 157px;
}

.Cart-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.Cart-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.Cart-text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0em 0.65em;
}

.CartMain {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 29px;
}

.HeaderMain {
  display: inline;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.HeaderBtn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  width: 85px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #e3e8f0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #343e5c
}

.DropMenu {
  margin-left: 115px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.MenuHeader {
  margin-right: 75px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1159px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    margin-right: 75px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1073px) {
  .DropMenu {
    margin-left: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>a {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
  .MenuHeader {
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  .DropMenu {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:443px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    display: none;
  }
  .CartMain {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}

.SecondMenuMain {
  margin-left: 115px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.SecondMenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.SecondMenu>li>a,
.SecondMenu>li>div>input {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b9bed1;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.SecondMenu>li>a:hover {
  color: #343e5c;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.SecondMenu>li>div>input {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b9bed1;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.SecondMenu>li>div>input:focus {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Support {
  padding-left: 280px;
}

.Bordered {
  border-left: 1px solid #b9bed1;
  border-right: 1px solid #b9bed1;
}

.Search {
  margin-left: 21px;
}
/* Слайдер,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, */

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px !important;
  height: 8px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
  color: #fefefe;


}
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
  padding-left: 183px !important;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon{
  padding-right: 183px !important;
}

.carousel-control-prev:hover {
  color: #fefefe;
}
.carousel{
  height:500px !important;
}
/* ThirdMenu??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? */

.ThirdMenuMain{
  background-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.ThirdMenu{
  margin-left: 115px;
  margin-right: 115px;
}

.ThirdMenu > ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-1{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 245px;
  height:56px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;

}
.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-1 > span{
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a1a8bd;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 49px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-1 > select{
  border: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  color: #343e5c;
  width: 107px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-1 > select > option{
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  color: #343e5c;
}

.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-2{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 693px;
  height: 56px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-2 > span {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a1a8bd;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  }

.Tablet{
  width: 163px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #f0f2f7;
  border: solid 1px #e3e8f0;
}
.Price{
  width: 64px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #f0f2f7;
  border: solid 1px #e3e8f0;
}

.Price-{
  margin-left: 6px !important;
  margin-right: 6px !important;
}

.Checbox-ThirdMenu{
  margin-left: 37px;
}
```

ThirdMenu.Js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class ThirdMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="ThirdMenuMain">
                <div className="ThirdMenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div className="ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-1">
                                    <span>SORT BY</span>
                                    <select name="" id="">
                                        <option value="best-match">BEST MATCH</option>
                                        <option value="popularity">POPULARITY</option>
                                        <option value="first-cheap">FIRST CHEAP</option>
                                        <option value="first-expensive">FIRT EXPENSIVE</option>
                                    </select>     
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="ThirdMenu-WhiteBox-2">
                                <span>KEYWORDS</span><input type="text" placeholder="Tablet" className="Tablet"/>
                                <span>PRICE</span><input type="text" className="Price" /><span className="Price-">-</span><input type="text" className="Price"/>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" className="Checbox-ThirdMenu"/><span>Free Shipping</span>

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

        );
    }
}

export default ThirdMenu;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import FaAlignJustify from 'react-icons/lib/fa/align-justify';
import FaShoppingCart from 'react-icons/lib/fa/shopping-cart';
import FaSearch from 'react-icons/lib/fa/search';
import Slider from "./Slider";


class Header extends Component {
     render() {
         return(
         <div>
             <div className="HeaderMain">
             <div className="DropMenu" >
             <ul className ="MenuButtons" id="TopNav" >
                     <li className="MenuHeader"><FaAlignJustify /></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><img src="/images/portland.jpg" alt="portlandlogo"/></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Delivery & Payment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><div className="CartMain">
                < FaShoppingCart /><span>Cart</span>
                <div className="Cart-container"><span className="Cart-span"></span><span className="Cart-text">0</span></div></div></li>
                <li className="Visible"><button className="HeaderBtn">Sign in</button></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="SecondMenuMain">
                <ul className="SecondMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">TOP SALES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BRAND FOCUS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HI-TECH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BEST SELLERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" className="Support">SUPPORT</a></li>
                    <li className="Bordered"><div><FaSearch className="Search" /><input placeholder="I`m looking for..."/></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>   
                    <Slider />  
            </div>
         </div>);


    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Зачем плодить вопросы, если можно было первый отредактировать?  Удали первый вопрос.... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785302/Не-пойму-почему-отходит-от-границ-блок#comment1234038_785302

Comment: Извиняюсь,забыл удалить неправильно заданный вопрос.

Comment: Ну просто надо было его править...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бегло посмотрел код, но проблема явно в inline-block. Попробуйте поставить

```
   .ThirdMenu > ul > li  {
      vertical-align: top;
      display: inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: Не помогло.Блоки выстроились в вертикальную колонку.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov, имеется ввиду добавьте строчку vertical-align. 
.ThirdMenu > ul > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}